Terragrunt workflow
Why my root.hcl configuration works if find_in_parent_folders() function suppose to find from bottom to top, but instead it actually looking for files in child folders?
root.hcl:
locals {
    account_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("account.hcl"))
    region_vars  = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("region.hcl"))
    env_vars     = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))
}

And the project structure:
    ├── demo
│   ├── account.hcl
│   └── us-east-1
│       ├── dev
│       │   ├── env.hcl
│       │   └── vpc
│       │       └── terragrunt.hcl
│       └── region.hcl
└── root.hcl

How does it work in such way?
My suspicion that it works in a way how include works in C++. When I run terragrunt apply from the bottom of some folders, it goes upward and simply copy-paste a content of config inside itself. But I didn't find any proves of it.

Where and how are you using root.hcl? What is the content of /us-east-1/dev/vpc/terragrunt.hcl?

@RuiJarimba I'm not sure what do you mean by where... It is used to run terragrunt configs. I run it from the /vpc folder and it unfolds to root.hcl
Speaking about region.hcl, just a few mocked include.
I'm not sure if this will help to answer a question, Rui.

Here is the for loop of the code of find_in_parent_folders() in iterating the directories. It starts from TerragruntConfigPath (which is some_directory/us-east-1/dev/vpc/terragrunt.hcl in your case) and each time removes one / and search/include the file, until it reaches the MaxFoldersToCheck or reaches the top directory of GIT/project:
some_directory/us-east-1/dev/vpc/terragrunt.hcl -> some_directory/us-east-1/dev/vpc/ -> some_directory/us-east-1/dev/ -> some_directory/us-east-1/ -> some_directory/

